# Making a small Stock Market Simulator

Tags: c++

Why am i not getting the proper result?
   For example the 3 day i am getting 30000 instead of 10303.

```
int main()
{

    float a;
    float p=10000;
    float r=.01;

    for (int day =1 ; day <=30; day++){
        a= p * pow(1+r, day);

    cout << day <<"---" <<a << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce:  http://ideone.com/I1tw4F

Comment: When I compiled this, I got the correct output, 10303 for day 3.